# php contact form doesn´t send the contents

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have several php forms on my website and they all email the contents of the form upon submitting the form. I had no issues until two weeks ago, but suddenly I have only started receiving empty emails (only the labels and not the user info) I have tried to fix the issue but no luck. Please help me.

My Form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../iletisimform.php">
 <p><span class="sss_cevap">İletişim Formu</span></p>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
   <tr>
   <td width="20%" align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="ad">Ad: </label></td>
   <td width="80%" align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><input name="ad" type="text" id="ad" size="35" maxlength="50" /> 
   *</td>
   </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="soyad">Soyad:</label></td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><input name="soyad" type="text" id="soyad" size="35" maxlength="50" /> 
          *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="firma">Firma:</label></td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><input name="firma" type="text" id="firma" size="35" maxlength="70" /> 
          *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="telefon">Telefon:</label></td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><input name="telefon" type="text" id="telefon" size="35" maxlength="12" /> 
          *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35" maxlength="70" /> 
          *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="mesaj">Mesaj:</label></td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><textarea name="mesaj" id="mesaj" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea> 
          *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><input name="promosyon" type="checkbox" id="promosyon" value="promogonder" />
          <label for="promosyon">Insuladd promosyonlarından haberdar olmak istiyorum...</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="Temizle"></label>
            <label for="temizle"></label>
          <input type="reset" name="temizle" id="temizle" value="Temizle" /></td>
          <td align="left" bgcolor="#EFF5F8"><label for="gönder"></label>
          <input type="submit" name="gönder" id="gönder" value="Gönder" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
          <p>* Alanları gereklidir<br />
    </p>
    </form>
```

---

My Script:

```
<?php


/* Subject and Email Variables */

    $emailSubject = 'Insuladd Bilgi Talebi!';
    $webMaster = 'info@insuladd.com.tr';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['ad'];
    $lastnameField = $_POST['soyad'];
    $companyField = $_POST['firma'];
    $telephoneField = $_POST['telefon'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $messageField = $_POST['mesaj'];
    $promotionField = $_POST['promosyon'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $ad <br>
Last Name: $soyad <br>
Company: $firma <br>
Telephone: $telefon <br>
Email: $email <br>
Message: $mesaj <br>
Promotion: $promosyon <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results rendered as HTML */

    $theResults = <<<EOD

EOD;
echo header ("Location: http://www.insuladd.com.tr/iletisim/tesekkurler.html");

?>
```

Comment: Someone, probably a bot, is submitting empty forms. You're not doing anything to prevent that.

Comment: Pro tip: **Always** validate user input.

Comment: Client side validate + server side re-validate before sending out the e-mail. Add error handling to your form blank submit, required fields, field rules, etc...

Comment: This is invalid `echo header ("Location:` remove `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see nothing functionally wrong that would prevent you from receiving the contents of the form. The only conclusion I can draw is that you're very likely receiving submissions from someone with empty content. In all likelihood it's from a bot.

That can easily be prevented by validating the user input to ensure that it is not empty. A way to do something along that lines could be...

```
<?php
    if ( empty($_POST['ad']) || empty($_POST['soyad']) || empty($_POST['firma']) || empty($_POST['telefon']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['mesaj']) || empty($_POST['promosyon']) )
    {
        header('Location: [Replace with url to page with error message]');
    }

/* Subject and Email Variables */

    $emailSubject = 'Insuladd Bilgi Talebi!';
    $webMaster = 'info@insuladd.com.tr';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['ad'];
    $lastnameField = $_POST['soyad'];
    $companyField = $_POST['firma'];
    $telephoneField = $_POST['telefon'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $messageField = $_POST['mesaj'];
    $promotionField = $_POST['promosyon'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $nameField <br>
Last Name: $lastnameField <br>
Company: $companyField <br>
Telephone: $telephoneField <br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Message: $messageField <br>
Promotion: $promotionField <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results rendered as HTML */

    $theResults = <<<EOD

EOD;
header ("Location: http://www.insuladd.com.tr/iletisim/tesekkurler.html");

?>
```

There are far more elegant ways of preventing the issue and implementing even the most basic of validation, but this gives you an idea of what it is you should attempt.

Comment: Hi, actually I have tried to send several emails myself and I again only received the labels of the form and not the associative content. Could it be anything to do with the version of PHP my host is using? I have switched between couple of versions on the cPanel but nothing changed... The weird thing is the exact same form was working perfectly fine 2 weeks ago!!!

Comment: Can you print the contents of the $_POST? You can do this by using `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I replaced the entire php script with print_r($_POST) and I get a blank page when I submit the form...

Comment: When you say replaced... you mean it came out looking something like `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`? And that came back blank with not an error or even a `array()` printed on the screen?

Comment: yes nothing, just a blank page... I am not a PHP expert but it seems really weird.

Comment: Try enabling error reporting. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); print_r($_POST); ?>` and see if that gives you an error back after you post to the script.

Comment: This is what I got: Array ( [ad] => [soyad] => [firma] => [telefon] => [email] => [mesaj] => [gÃ¶nder] => GÃ¶nder )

Comment: It's odd that they are posting blank instead of containing a value. When you posted the form did you populate the fields before submitting? However, I did notice an error with the script that I didn't in my initial cursory glance. You were emailing non-existent variables. ie: You were calling $ad in the email when the assignment was `$nameField = $_POST['ad'];` I've updated my initial answer to reflect the proper variables.

Comment: Yes I did populate some inputs before submitting the forms. How should I fix that error? Maybe that causes the problem???

Comment: This is invalid `echo header ("Location:` remove `echo` @user2077997

Comment: If you are putting data into the fields before submitting the form and the $_POST is still reporting as the fields are empty when you print the array then that's very different a problem. Try checking your $_REQUEST variable instead. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); print_r($_REQUEST); ?>`

Comment: Fred: You're right. That is wrong and something I should have caught in the first glance, but unfortunately that's not the root problem. Thank you for pointing that out though. It's been awhile since I've used a location redirect myself so I didn't think twice about it.

Comment: I tested the OP's code and I received the email without a hitch. Something else is causing this, or is being blocked. @Majii

Comment: @Fred, that's the weird thing. If his $_POST is returning essentially empty values for the keys then there is something very funky going wrong well beyond his scripting.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed this `...empty($_POST['promosyon']) || )` the `||` in there should be taken out. @Majii otherwise it's expecting more.

Comment: Hello, I got it. You were right about calling the non existing the variable. The weird thing is it has always been this way and never caused any issues. It is working now. I must definitely get a more stable system in place. One with a database to back up all the data. Many thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Also accept Majii's answer by clicking the white checkmark till it turns Green, if you're not aware of that yet, since it has been solved. Cheers @user2077997

Comment: @Fred: Thanks, I got a little overzealous with my copy/paste job there.

Comment: You're welcome. @Majii OP probably is not aware about how things are done around here. Will `+1` but OP needs to close the question. Cheers